Why when using Shor's Algorithm to factor 33 am I getting 5 as a period half of the time?
When using Shor's algorithm to try to factor 33 I expect the period found to be 10,  however when I run it using qiskit and qasm simulator I keep getting 5 and 10 appearing as the most common periods and cannot figure out why 5 is showing up (beside maybe weird rounding when converting phase, not sure but this is my best guess). Most of the actual Shor section I got from a qiskit walkthrough of Shor's but it was for factoring 15.
Here is the code:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, Aer, transpile
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram
from math import gcd
from numpy.random import randint
import pandas as pd
from fractions import Fraction
print("Imports Successful")

def c_amod33(a, power):
    """Controlled multiplication by a mod 33"""
    # List of valid 'a' values for mod 33 
    valid_a_values = [5, 7, 8, 10, 13, 14, 16, 17, 19, 20, 23, 25, 26, 28, 29, 31, 32]
    if a not in valid_a_values:
        raise ValueError(f"'a' must be one of {valid_a_values}")

    U = QuantumCircuit(6)  # Assume 6 qubits for values up to 33
    
    for _ in range(power):
        if a == 5:
            #U.swap(3, 4)
            #U.swap(2, 3)
            #U.swap(1, 2)
            #U.swap(0, 1)
            U.swap(0, 1)
            U.swap(1, 2)
            U.swap(2, 3)
            U.swap(3, 4)
        if a in [5]:
            for q in range(6):
                U.x(q)
 
    U = U.to_gate()
    U.name = f"{a}^{power} mod 33"
    c_U = U.control()
    return c_U

n_count = 12
a = 5

def qft_dagger(n):
    """n-qubit QFTdagger the first n qubits in circ"""
    qc = QuantumCircuit(n)
    # Don't forget the Swaps!
    for qubit in range(n//2):
        qc.swap(qubit, n-qubit-1)
    for j in range(n):
        for m in range(j):
            qc.cp(-np.pi/float(2**(j-m)), m, j)
        qc.h(j)
    qc.name = "QFT†"
    return qc

# Create QuantumCircuit with n_count counting qubits
# plus 6 qubits for U to act on

qc = QuantumCircuit(n_count + 6, n_count+6)

# Initialize counting qubits
# in state |+>
for q in range(n_count):
    qc.h(q)

# And auxiliary register in state |1>
qc.x(n_count)

# Step dividing line
qc.barrier()

# Do controlled-U operations
for q in range(n_count):
    qc.append(c_amod33(a, 2**q),
             [q] + [i+n_count for i in range(6)])
    
# Step dividing line
qc.barrier()

# Measure storage register
for i in range(12, 18):
    qc.measure(i, i)
    
# Step dividing line
qc.barrier()

# Do inverse-QFT
qc.append(qft_dagger(n_count), range(n_count))

# Step dividing line
qc.barrier()

# Measure circuit
qc.measure(range(n_count), range(n_count))
qc.draw(output="mpl", fold=-1)  # -1 means 'do not fold'

aer_sim = Aer.get_backend('qasm_simulator')
t_qc = transpile(qc, aer_sim)
counts = aer_sim.run(t_qc).result().get_counts()
plot_histogram(counts)

rows, measured_phases = [], []
for output in counts:
    output_trimmed = output[6:]
    decimal = int(output_trimmed, 2)  # Convert (base 2) string to decimal
    phase = decimal/(2**n_count)  # Find corresponding eigenvalue
    measured_phases.append(phase)
    # Add these values to the rows in our table:
    rows.append([f"{output_trimmed}(bin) = {decimal:>3}(dec)",
                 f"{decimal}/{2**n_count} = {phase:.2f}"])
# Print the rows in a table
headers=["Register Output", "Phase"]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
print(df)

def continued_fraction(x, max_terms):
    """Generate the continued fraction representation of x up to the given max_terms."""
    cf = []
    for _ in range(max_terms):
        n = int(x)
        cf.append(n)
        x -= n
        #if x == 0:
        if abs(x) < 1e-10:
            break
        x = 1 / x
    return cf

def fraction_from_continued_fraction(cf):
    """Convert a continued fraction list to a Fraction."""
    if not cf:
        return Fraction(0)
    frac = Fraction(cf[-1])
    for a in reversed(cf[:-1]):
        frac = a + 1 / frac
    return frac

rows = []
for phase in measured_phases:
    # Get the continued fraction representation
    cf = continued_fraction(phase, 33)
    # Convert continued fraction to a fraction
    frac = fraction_from_continued_fraction(cf)
    # Limit denominator 
    frac = frac.limit_denominator(33)
    
    rows.append([phase,
                 f"{frac.numerator}/{frac.denominator}",
                 frac.denominator])

# Print as a table
headers = ["Phase", "Fraction", "Guess for r"]
df = pd.DataFrame(rows, columns=headers)
print(df)

# Calculate the frequency of each value in the "Guess for r" column
frequency_df = df['Guess for r'].value_counts().reset_index()
frequency_df.columns = ['Guess for r', 'Frequency']


# Print the frequency DataFrame
print("\nFrequency of 'Guess for r' values:")
print(frequency_df)

Thanks in advanced!

I do not quite understand why this result is surprising to you? It is the expected behavior — if I understand correctly and you exponentiate $a = 5$ which is of order $r = 10$ in $\mathbb Z_{33}^*$, and if you simply solve the frequency you observe by expanding in a continued fraction as Shor originally proposed in [Shor94] without searching or trying multiples or similar.
You will observe a peak with index $z \in [0, r) \cap \mathbb Z$, and the order returned by the continued fraction expansion is $r / \gcd(z, r)$, so you can get $1$, $2$, $5$ or $10$ (where $5$ and $10$ are the most probable outcomes), or something else potentially if you observe a frequency far from the peak (which is improbable).
(Ps. I did not read your code in any detail but I think the above is the piece you are missing.)
